# Uploading multiple files to PHP and storing Filepath etc in SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I am attempting to upload multiple files to a folder using PHP and then add the file path etc to a SQL database.

When I remove the if statement that runs the database query, all files selected are uploaded to the specified directory successfully and the 'success' echo is printed the same number of times as there are uploaded files, as expected.

When I add the if statement back in, that causes only the first file to upload and nothing else to echo. Only one echo of 'success' is printed for the single uploaded file and neither the status:success or error:... are printed and nothing is added to the database.

Below is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if (count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0) {
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {

            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

            if ($tmpFilePath != "") {

                $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                $filePath = "../../uploads/files/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                    echo "success";

                    include './includes/db/databaseUploads.php';

                    $files[] = $shortname;
                    $dbuserId = $_SESSION['login_id'];

                    $queryAddFile = "INSERT INTO `files`(`id`, `file_name`, `folder`, `user_id`, `upload_time`, `modify_time`) VALUES (NULL,$shortname,'root',$dbuserId',NULL,NULL)";

                    //Removing the below if statement allows me to upload multiple files but obviously removes database functionality.
                    if ($connectionUploads->query($queryAddFile) === TRUE) {
                        echo '{"status":"success"}';
                    } else {
                        echo '{"status":"error", "response":"'.$connectionUploads->error.'"}';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    echo "no post"; 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: Do try and avoid getting into the habit of comparing things to literal `TRUE` inside an `if` clause. Most of the time `if (x)` is sufficient and `if (x === TRUE)` is just wasted verbosity.